# Can't open QGIS 3.8 plugin manager on OSX

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I have not been able to open the plugin manager in QGIS 3.8.  I am running Sierra OSX.  This is the message that I get when I try to open the plugin manager:

> An error occurred during execution of following code:
>   pyplugin_installer.instance().showPluginManagerWhenReady()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'pyplugin_installer' is not defined
>
> Python version:
>   3.6.8 (default, Jun 25 2019, 16:00:16) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   3.8.0-Zanzibar 'Zanzibar', exported

Also (this might be a related problem), when I open QGIS, I get the following dialogs:

> Couldn't load plugin 'DigitizingTools' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'ImageServerConnector' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'latlontools' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'qgis2web' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math' 
>   Couldn't load plugin 'quick_map_services' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'MetaSearch' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
>
> Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
>
> An error occurred during execution of following code:
>   pyplugin_installer.initPluginInstaller()

I am running Python 3.7.3 using PyEnv

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like I figured out why this was happening. In my post above I wrote that I was using version 3.7.3, but I had also tried running QGIS with version 3.6.8 using pyenv.  I kept getting the same errors using 3.6.8 as well. 
What solved my problem was to install the version of Python (3.6.8) that came with the QGIS (3.8) installer and the error messages went away and I am now able to open the plugin manager.